# Javascript issues in Safari and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, safari

The problem is that the slider on the home and products page only works with firefox chrome and Opera. It just fails to move in either IE or Safari. The second issue is about how the site scales on mobile devices. I've looked into mobile event handling, but with less than great results.

http://dextersaltmedia.net78.net/

Comment: straight from the console: `TypeError: $(...).responsiveSlides is not a function` :P i don't get any slider and i'm on FF30.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasting the entire responsiveslides.jquery.js file into the console makes the thing work normally, so your problem is in

`<script type="text/javascript" src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>`

The only issue is that the library module never runs, even though the library gets included as a file.

Put your script tags at the end of the page, that might work better. Or try placing the library script tag at the end alone.

Ideally though, you should just bunch up jquery and the library file in one .js file and include that one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I have merged the 2 scripts and although it still functions in firefox and Chrome. I still can't get IE or Safari to play nice.